# How simulate logic in CSS selector

Tags: css, wordpress

I built a church site where the nav bar was to show only a few pages when it displayed on the splash page, then show a few more links everywhere else in the site. I used CSS selectors that reference WordPress page ID and menu link numbers. But as the site grows, this is unmanageable. Can someone advise an efficient method?

```
.page-id-2 .nav-primary #menu-item-1193,
.page-id-2 .nav-primary #menu-item-855,
.page-id-2 .nav-primary #menu-item-857,
.page-id-2 .nav-primary #menu-item-856,
.page-id-2 .nav-primary #menu-item-863,
.page-id-2 .nav-primary #menu-item-916,
.page-id-2 .nav-primary #menu-item-1116,
.page-id-2 .nav-primary #menu-item-15433,
.page-id-2 .nav-primary #menu-item-16122,
.page-id-2 .nav-primary #menu-item-15658 {
    display:none;
}
```

[site with the live code here...](http://www.tulsaunity.com/)

Comment: Are the menu items even unique?

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal is here. What happens? What would you like to happen? By the way, if you want to select all combinations that have something in common, use `*`. Like `#menu-item-*` (maybe more stars are needed - don't remember)

Comment: On interior pages, the only way to control the nav bar is more and more CSS turning off menu items. Scroll to the bottom of the splash page and click something like Privacy Statement. It's a mess.

Comment: You could add the `page-id-*` class that's assigned to body to the items you want to show on a given `page-id`. So for `/social-events/`  that's `.page-id-837`. You could add the `.page-id-837` class name to the nav elements you want to show on the page, then in CSS do `.nav-primary .menu-item { display: none; } .page-id-837 .nav-primary .page-id-837 { display: block; }` and add that for each of the `page-id`'s.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your source code from the site, you can use those selections:

```
.nav-primary > div > ul#menu-primary-navigation > li

shortly ul#menu-primary-navigation > li
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the php files, you can use the is_home() function and show one menu for the homepage and another one for the internal pages.

You can read more here
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/

If you don't have access to the php files and you need to use only css, you can switch it

You can hide all the links on the homepage and only show the links that you want, for example:

```
.page-id-1 .nav-primary .menu-item{
    display:none;
}

.page-id-1 .nav-primary #menu-item-1193,
.page-id-1 .nav-primary #menu-item-855,
.page-id-1 .nav-primary #menu-item-857,
.page-id-1 .nav-primary #menu-item-856{
    display:block;
}
```

Assuming that page-id-1 is the homepage.

Comment: Frank, I was hoping for your type of completely different approach. Yes I can access the PHP. Let me try this approach this week. Then I will come back and either mark yours as the solution ... or rephrase my question. Thanks all who replied.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't simulate logic in CSS.**

You should create two separate menus.

- **Menu-A** will include the few links you want to be on the **Home page**.
- **Menu-B** will include the items you want on all other pages.

Once you do that, set the default `display` for **Menu-A** to `none`.

Then you can use the `.home` selector in CSS to set the `display` of **Menu-A** to `Block` or whatever

Then set **Menu-B** to `display:none` on the homepage.

Here's a quick summary of what I mean

```
.menu-a {
  display: none
}

.home .menu-a {
  display: block
}

.home .menu-B {
  display: none;
}
```

This will give you a lot more control.

See this guide if you are not sure how to register a second menu.

[How to Add More Navigation Menus to your WordPress Theme](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-menus-to-wordpress/)

Comment: Well you can try it like I did, then watch it slowly collapse under the load. Wink. I'll be working on the dual menu idea this week.